# Xojo MacOs Vs. Windows? EndOFLine issue

Tags: realbasic, xojo

So I created a program on Xojo(MacOS) that parses paragraphs using EndofLine. However, when I run it on a Windows operating system it doesn't parse it at all. Does Window operating systems recognize EndofLine or Chr(10)+Chr(13) in Xojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xojo's EndOfLine constant is indeed different depending on the platform you use it for.

You have two choices of dealing with this:

Explicitly use a platform specific constant:

```
EndOfLine.Windows gives CR+LF
EndOfLine.Unix gives LF
```

The better way, especially if you import data from outside the program, e.g. when reading from a file or from a network socket, is to normalize the line delimiters for your internal use, like this:

```
normalizedString = ReplaceLineEndings (importedString, EndOfLine)
```

Now, you can use EndOfLine with normalizedString, e.g. to split it into single lines:

```
dim lines() as String = normalizedString.Split (EndOfLine)
```

When you write this string back, you'll automatically have it in the system's format already.

However, when you export your text to a system where you know it expects them in a certain format, convert them back to that format like this:

```
// E.g, if you export them for a Mac:
outputString = ReplaceLineEndings (internalString, EndOfLine.Unix)
```

Answer (score 1):

`EndOfLine` is always platform dependent, so in case of Windows, its value is `chr(13)+chr(10)`, while on macOS it's `chr(10)`. You can reach these platform-specific values directly by using `EndOfLine.Windows` and `EndOfLine.OSX`.

To normalise the line endings in a string, you can use the [`ReplaceLineEndings()`](https://docs.xojo.com/ReplaceLineEndings) function.